# MySQL How to SELECT where field equals something in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Take two example tables:

```
TableOne
+----+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
| id | uid      | thingone    | thingtwo   | thingthree |  |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|  1 | 7        | 0           | 1          | 1          |  |
|  2 | 8        | 1           | 1          | 0          |  |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

and

```
TableTwo
+----+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
| id | oid      | thingone    | thingtwo   | thingthree |  |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|  1 | 7        | Apple       | Coconut    | Grape      |  |
|  2 | 8        | Potato      | Orange     | Banana     |  |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

So in this example userid 7 would get Coconut and Grape, but not Apple. Userid 8 would get Potato and Orange, but not banana. I am wanting to do this the most efficient way and I realize I could do two separate queries with some php processing, but I want to do it with a single query if feasible.

What I need to do is (in a single query) get the row from TableOne by id and then select the row from TableTwo where theoid = the id of TableOne but only get the corresponding row from TableTwo if it is 1 and not 0 in TableOne.

Can any one help please?

Comment: Kindly show us the query that you tried.

Comment: I do not have one yet, I am very new sorry. I know the abstract though I need to "SELECT * FROM TableTwo WHERE oid='7' [IF THE FIELD = 1 IN TableOne]" it is the part between the [ and ] I dont know how to do.

Comment: No worries, atleast you know where you need to go.

Comment: provide your desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `IF` and comparing the columns from both tables 1 by 1. To compare the tabletwo from tableone you need to use JOIN, in this query I use a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT a.id, a.`uid`, 
IF(a.`thingone`=1, b.`thingone`, NULL) AS thingone,
IF(a.`thingtwo`=1, b.`thingtwo`, NULL) AS thingtwo,
IF(a.`thingthree`=1, b.`thingthree`, NULL) AS thingthree FROM tableone a
LEFT JOIN tabletwo b ON uid=oid;
```

Check [MySQL IF() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) for more details.

Comment: This seems like it would be perfect! I am confused about the a and b parts, I do not see those in the docs. Where does the a and b comefrom like where it says "tableone a"? Thank you!

Comment: @Trinity, they are called table alias, _"When you create an alias on a table, it is either because you plan to list the same table name more than once in the FROM clause (ie: self join), or you want to shorten the table name to make the SQL statement shorter and easier to read."_ check this [MySQL Alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php).

Answer (score 0):

you need to make relational tables and then use join query

Comment: I am kind of new, could you provide the query please? And instructions on how to make them relational? Thank you for your response.

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please provide some explanations on how this answer's the OP's question.

Comment: this web site give a guide to you : https://launchschool.com/books/sql/read/table_relationships

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
select case when t1.thingone = 1 then t2.thingone else '' end,
       case when t1.thingtwo = 1 then t2.thingtwo else '' end,
       case when t1.thingthree = 1 then t2.thingthree else '' end
from TableOne t1 join TableTwo t2 on t1.uid=t2.oid
```

You might need to concatenate these three or convert them into three rows, depending how how the three things should be represented.

Comment: I appreciate this response, I hope I can build on it. I will say that there will be many more columns in the real thing so I was hoping not to have to handcode all of them, but this is still a solution to my problem if I can get it to work. Thank you!